# Имя Изяслав

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Что означает славянское имя Изяслав. -Слав - понятно, а первая часть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По данным "Именослова" В.Казакова, Изяслав - 'изымающий (берущий) славу'. Сын Владимира I. Изя-слав Ярославич. вел. кн. киевский (1054-1068; 1069-1073; 1077-1078).
В Словаре русских личных имен Н.А.Петровского об имени Изяслав говорится, что оно произошло от др.-рус. изяти - 'взять', 'брать' и слава 'слава'. В общем, источники не противоречат друг другу.